# VBA Insert static value into SQL table

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've used VBA to insert into an SQL table before but its always been using values in cells. I have three columns in my table where I need to add just a static value (so no cell reference).

The code I have so far is:

```
stSQL = "INSERT INTO Client_Notes " & _
    "(ID, Category, RefID, Name, Notes, Date_Loaded, Latest) " & _
    " VALUES (" & _
    "'" & 1 & "', " & _
    "'" & 1 & "', " & _
    "'" & Sheets("Missing").ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Value & "', " & _
    "'" & Sheets("Missing").ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Value & "', " & _
    "'" & Sheets("Details").ActiveCell.Value & "', " & _
    "'" & Date & "', " & "'" & _
    "'" & 1 & "'" & _
    ")"
```

The error I keep getting is when trying to insert 1 as a value. I'm sure its straight forward but feel like I had tried every quote and comma combination going.

Thanks in advance

So the new code now looks like so, where I am getting Subscript Out Of Range:

```
stSQL = "INSERT INTO Client_Notes " & _
    "(ID, Category, RefID, Name, Notes, Date_Loaded, Latest) " & _
    " VALUES (" & _
    "1, " & _
    "1, " & _
    "'" & Sheets("Missing").Range("L" & i).Offset(0, -10).Value & "', " & _
    "'" & Sheets("Missing").Range("L" & i).Offset(0, -9).Value & "', " & _
    "'" & Sheets("Details").Range("L" & i).Value & "', " & _
    "'" & Date & "', " & _
    "1)"
```

Comment: You should only use values within quotation marks if it is a text field you are referring to.  Are `ID` and `Category` and `Latest` text fields or numeric fields?  Also, you have a syntax error at `"', " & "'" & _` `"'" & 1 & "'" & _` `")"` as that is equivalent to `"', ''1')"` which has a double single-quotation mark.

Comment: These are numeric fields

Comment: `Sheet` objects do not have an `ActiveCell` property.  What are you trying to do with `Sheets("Missing").ActiveCell` and `Sheets("Details").ActiveCell`?  And which sheet is the `ActiveCell` actually on when your code runs?

Comment: Can you please include what the error actually says? It's difficult to determine what the problem is without all the details. Having said that, if these are all numeric fields then none of the values should be wrapped in quotation marks.

Comment: The error I'm getting is Object doesn't support this property or method. Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is I have a client records in a spread sheet which I'm pulling from an SQL table. The user goes through this data and makes notes. I want to write the notes back to a separate SQL table but some records will not have notes. So far I've got the macro looping through the notes field until it find a note. Then it moves across and takes the relevant detail (offset) but I also want it to record the note that's been added, which is the active cell. Probably a better way I'm sure.

Comment: Ok so I have changed ActiveCell for the Range("L" & i).Offset and I'm now getting Subscript out of range

Comment: What is the value of `i`?

Comment: i = 10 as for formatting/layout reasons my data set starts on row 10 (column L).

Comment: And you are getting the "Subscript out of range" error on the line (including the continuations) setting the `strSQL` variable?  It might be best if you edit the question to show the new code.  (But leave the old code there as well, or else Kamil's answer will become meaningless.)

Comment: Updated with new code thanks

Comment: Do you have sheets called "Missing" and "Details"?  As far as I can see, that is the only source of a subscript out of range error on those lines.

Comment: Can you show the `For` loop that runs for `i` and also how you determine the end row to loop until?

Comment: Unreal YowE3K!!! Its been staring me in the face all day and it turns out that I'm referencing the wrong sheet with "Details"!!! Amazing what a fresh pair of eyes can do! Thank you all for your help.